# Harmon.ie - To and From columns contains Exchange info

Tags: harmon.ie

After uploading emails to a document library containing the Email Content Type (generated and added using Powershell scripts found in this article), the To and From columns now looks like this:

/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=5457fe27114d487298a338a915cc38f2-**** ****** <****.*****@********.com>

[image: Obfuscated example]

What can I do to make it save and display only the name and/or email address of the sender/receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Are you running the free or enterprise edition? what version?
Attach the output of "About"

If you are running the Enterprise edition, log a case to support@harmon.ie and disclose the name of the company facing this issue so that we upgrade them to our latest version. Seems to be an old issue with email client with multiple email addresses defined.

---- Jean

Comment: It's an Enterprise Edition. I will log a case, thank you.